# ¿Como ejecutar vue create en directorio inferior, con instalacion local del CLI?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

En mi carpeta raiz ***aplicaciones*** ejecuté: `npm install @vue/cli` que me creo las carpetas node_modules y package-lock.json, el problema que surge es que en esa carpeta **no puedo ejecutar**:

```
vue create formulario-sistema
```

porque me sale: "vue" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo.

así que tengo que ir a `./node_modules/.bin/` y luego ejecutar `vue create aprendiendo-vue ../../` para que me lo cree en *aplicaciones*, pero me lo esta creando dentro de bin.

¿Cuál seria el comando correcto para crear un proyecto vue en otro directorio?

Comment: Porque no has instalado `vue-cli` de manera global? `npm install -g @vue/cli`. Si lo instalas de manera global podras crear el proyecto en el directorio que desees

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya se Encontró una solución:

ejecutar: `sh ./node_modules/.bin/vue create formulario-sistema` desde la carpeta raiz aplicaciones, como Cmder de laragon permite ejecutar comandos linux en windows. se ejecuta una instalacion limpia, sin la necesidad de copiar de .bin a aplicaciones.

Answer (score 0):

¿Qué tal algo como esto?

```sh
./node_modules/.bin/vue create formulario-sistema
```

Ejecutado desde tu carpeta raíz **aplicaciones**.